Remote desktop option doesn't show up in Sharing in 24.04
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=24.04&architecture=amd64&lts=true in Virtual Box VM and turned to instructions how to share RD https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html. The sequence starts with a link to Install Gnome Remote Desktop which doesn't work and shows a pop-up window which says No Apps Available. I installed gnome-remote-desktop manually via apt-get and the service is up. Still, no Remote Desktop option in Sharing appeared. What am I missing?
I didn't have this issue with 23.10

It's moved to Settings -> System -> Remote Desktop

I installed Ubuntu 24 and the settings -> system -> remoteDesktop panel was literally blank.  Very strange.  So I ended up noticing that gnome-remote-desktop wasn't installed.  This was on a Vim3 SBA Arm version of the distro.  But maybe the solution is the same.
I just removed gnome-remote-desktop if it was there, and then install gnome-remote-desktop.  And then the panel under the settings was no longer blank and showed all the options.  I hope this helps anyone.
